# Uniquely reverse an arithmetic OR operation

Tags: coding-theory, discrete-optimization

i'm not sure if this is more a CS or math problem, but i'll try my luck here first:

- given a pool of unique 32 bit integers (the values are under my control)
- up to 8 integers are randomly taken from the pool (a value can not be picked more than once)
- the integers are combined with an arithmetic OR into a new 32 bit value

Given only the result integer, and knowledge about all possible values (= the pool), all integers taken from the pool must be uniquely identified
(at this time, the number of input integers is unknown, it could be anything from 1 to 8)

Task: Maximize the size of the pool of integers

Currently i only have the trivial case:
32 values in the pool, every value has only one bit from 0 to 31 set

Is there any way to increase the size of the pool of integers?

Comment: You can give an upper bound as follows: If your pool $P$ has size $n$, then the map $\mathrm{OR}\colon P\sqcup (P\times P)\sqcup (P\times P\times P)\sqcup P^4\sqcup P^5\sqcup P^6\sqcup P^7\sqcup P^8\to \{0,1\}^{32}$ must be injective. Thus, the size of the first set (which is $\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{8}$) must be smaller than $2^{32}$, which gives $n\leq62$. But that's not a complete answer.

Comment: @student91 thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, being a programmer, but not a mathematician, i have a hard time deciphering it.

From your answer i assume, a pool size of 62 should be possible? Is there any hint on how to achieve that?

Comment: no, I'm just saying that a pool of 63+ is certainly _not_ possible, so 32 is pretty close

Comment: I am almost certain that your trivial solution is optimal. You should either severely decrease the "8" to e.g. 3 or 4, or increase the "32" to e.g. 256 or something. Although I do not have a complete proof that these numbers will work. If you are interested I could try to write something out.

Comment: @student91 thanks for your continued interest. A solution with 4 input values would still be valuable for me.